# Wrap long post title in new line

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap

I have some of my post titles quite long and when viewed on my mobile phone, the long title text gets cut at the end of the screen width like it disappears in.

What I want to do is for long title text to continue on a new line rather than a section of it disappearing.

I have tried the following but not working:

```
.vtitle {
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break:break-all;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

CSS:

```
.vtitle {
    font: Normal 34px 'Tulpen One', Dosis, sans-serif !important;
    padding-top: 12px;
    word-break: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Throw us a fiddle, also, take out `nowrap`

Comment: I have a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LFzSE/6/) but it keeps  bypassing the success function and displaying only the alert

Comment: Include, in the question, sufficient code (HTML and CSS) to actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue myself and thanks to those that responded. The fix to this was simply using the white space like this:

```
.vtitle {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Adding the `!important` forced the custom css to override the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.vtitle {
    word-break:break-word;
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2X42H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, wanted to try it on a fiddle, but it seems like it works :

http://jsfiddle.net/n7UTK/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>A long title in a tiny place.</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title
{
     width   : 100px;  
}
```

And it also works on my mobile phone ...